# Website with Google cloud compute

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Total NOOB question. I want to setup a website on google cloud compute platform with:

1. static IP/IP range(external API requirement)
2. simple front-end
3. average to low traffic with a maximum of few thousand requests a
   day.
4. separate database instance.

I went through the documentation of services offered Google and Amazon. Not fully sure what is the best way to go about it. Understand that there is no right answer.

Answer (score 2):

A viable solution is:

- Spawn up an `n1-standard` instance on GCP (I prefer to use Debian)
- Get a static IP, which is free if you don't let it dangling.
- Depending upon your DB type choose Cloud SQL for structured data or Cloud Datastore for unstructured data
- Nginx is a viable option for web-server. [Get started here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Rest is upon you. What kind of stack are you using to build your app? How are you gonna deploy your code to instance? You might later wanna use Docker and k8s to get flexibility between cloud providers and scaling needs.

Comment: Thanks Vikram, Interesting. I will check that out.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of creating the website you want would be Google App Engine with the Datastore as DB. However it doesn't support static IP's, this is due to a design choice. Is this absolutely mandatory?

> App Engine does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses
>   to an application. In order to optimize the network path between an
>   end user and an App Engine application, end users on different ISPs or
>   geographic locations might use different IP addresses to access the
>   same App Engine application. DNS might return different IP addresses
>   to access App Engine over time or from different network locations.

Comment: Hi Serge, Thanks for the suggestion. I was leaning towards app engine too. It seems to be close to perfect as far as ease of development and infrastructure management aspects. But unfortunately, the third party APIs I'll be using will only work from white-listed IPs(aarghh...). So yes, that's important.